# Creating Local Android Service

Tags: android

I created a local android service.
When user selects the start button then a service is started and an inner class which extends from Activity and implements the runnable and SensorEventListener is created.

I would like to get the x,y,z coordinates of the mobile device before and after the device is locked (screen monitor becomes off and black and the device is locked). How do I do this task?

Thanks,
Eyall

Answer (score 0):

There are System Broadcasts for the display turning on & off.
So you should register for them and try to save them in different data structures.

There are these Intents you could register for:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
```

They may need special permissions (check logcat for that).

Comment: I think you meant SCREEN_OFF in the second line?